# Not able to setup Devops in Azure

Tags: azure-devops

Sorry for a silly question in advance.

1. I have an MSDN subscription.
2. I am trying to learn Azure Devops by doing. I intend to have a CI/ CD pipeline.
3. My repository is in GitHub.
4. I created a web-app and through 'Deployment Centre' tried to create a deployment pipeline.
   The steps 'Source Control', 'Build Provider', 'Configure' and 'Summary'.
   Whenever I click on to 'Finish', I get the following message:

> Failed to set up deployment: You can't register a new application in
>   Azure Active Directory. Learn more:
>   https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=843472. More details:
>   Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.

Please help me to understand the following:

1. Why I need to register my application with AD if I do not want to have any authentication.
2. And how to get around this issue.

Few points which may be helpful:

1. I am using an MSDN subscription.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why I need to register my application with AD if I do not want to have any authentication.

When you configure CD pipeline though the Deployment Centre, Azure needs to authenticate and authorize the Build provider applications (eg.Azure pipelines of Azure devops).

Below are services it provides for app integrating with Azure AD. Check the [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-how-applications-are-added#why-do-applications-integrate-with-azure-ad) for more information.

- Application authentication and authorization
- User authentication and authorization
- SSO using federation or password
- User provisioning and synchronization
- Role-based access control - Use the directory to define application roles to perform role-based authorization checks in an application
- OAuth authorization services - Used by Office 365 and other Microsoft applications to authorize access to APIs/resources
- Application publishing and proxy - Publish an application from a private network to the internet

> And how to get around this issue.

To get the permission to add integrated applications. You can follow below steps (The directory administrator has permission to change this setting). See document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/azure-rm-endpoint?view=azure-devops#the-user-is-not-authorized-to-add-applications-in-the-directory).
- Choose Azure Active Directory in the left navigation bar.

- Ensure you are editing the appropriate directory corresponding to the user subscription. If not, select Switch directory and log in using the appropriate credentials if required.
- In the MANAGE section choose Users.
- Choose User settings.
- In the App registrations section, change Users can register applications to Yes.

[image]

If you have only guest permission in the directory. Please refer to the steps in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/azure-rm-endpoint?view=azure-devops#the-user-has-only-guest-permission-in-the-directory).

I would like to recommend below links for you to start up with azure devops:

[Get started documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/get-started/?view=azure-devops)

[Get started with Azure DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/get-started-with-devops/)

[Build applications with Azure DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/paths/build-applications-with-azure-devops/)

[Deploy applications with Azure DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/paths/deploy-applications-with-azure-devops/)

Comment: This is fine for a test AD but you should not really turn that setting on for production.  Given the error the op is getting, it would seem that is the case given they do not have permissions.  It effectively allows users to create other users, albeit for a defined purpose.  It also creates clutter in the AD with AzDO often ending up with duplicate connections.  If you want to use an AD app (and you should) then ask your AD admin to create it for you.  If they say no, well that is their job.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely caused by the subscription connection that AzDO tries to set up automatically so it can deploy. It creates an app registration and a secret key which it uses as uid/pwd.  If you don't have permission in the Ad underlying your subscription this will fail.

If you can get someone to set this up for you then you can provide these detail and create the subscription connection yourself.

Edited : The Service Connections are in Project Settings > Pipelines > Service Connections.  Setting up a new one for Azure ARM provides four options, the default of which is Service Principal, this is the AD Application is it trying to setup.  If you configure this manually you also have the choice of using managed identity (will likely need the same permissions) or a publish profile, which you should be able to obtain from the web app you setup.